# Android Studio Build Error Duplicate Entry

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I tried to build APK but i took an error message.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.class

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.pc.gozlukdenemexxx"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Hello @ThomasSmyth. Firstly, i rebuilt the project and then i cleaned it .Thats all.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. In ConstraintLayout.java file i deleted this method :

```
class ConstraintLayout extends View {
    public ConstraintLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }
```

But i wonder, deleting this method cause more problems?